# SuppressMessage for multiple targets

Tags: .net, config, .net-assembly, code-analysis

My solution contains a set of projects (they will be keep adding every often). I want to suppress a set of code analysis messages for all the projects.

Currently I included all the projects as follows.

```
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1020:AvoidNamespacesWithFewTypes", Scope = "namespace", Target = "xxx")]
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1020:AvoidNamespacesWithFewTypes", Scope = "namespace", Target = "yyy")]
```

The problem is when I want to suppress another message or add another project (more likely to happen), I have to specify the suppress message many a times, which turning to be a monstrous job.

Is there a way to specify the messages or targets in groups? I just want to reduce the maintenance overhead.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to disable the CA1020 rule entirely, or just suppress violations for specific namespaces?

Comment: It is just one rule I have mentioned. There are quite a few I am suppressing, some are to be suppressed entirely and some need to be imposed on specific namespaces only.

Comment: Would disabling the rule entirely hide issues that you consider to be problems?